# Is there a way for VS Code markdown preview to show the location of the file?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Suppose I open a markdown file `dir1/README.md` and open the markdown preview.
The editor shows that the path of the file is `dir1 > README.md`.
The preview shows only the name of the file, `README.md` as shown below:

[image: example]

Suppose that I click on the relative link to `../dir2/README.md` in the preview window.
Now I get this:

[image]

If there are many `README.md` files across many directories, the file name is insufficient to tell which file is actually rendered.

Is there a way to show the path of the file being rendered in the preview just like the markdown editor shows at the top of the window the project-relative path of the file in the editor?

- Nicolas.

Comment: you can file a feature request with the markdown extension